# HTML5 Canvas game has bug where first puzzle piece changes to a different piece when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I think I just need a fresh set of eyes on this game I'm working on.

It's a sliding image puzzle (where you split an image into pieces and display them back in a random order, I then remove a single piece of the puzzle and the user has to click on each puzzle piece to move it around and thus put the image back together)

The full code is here: https://github.com/Integralist/HTML5-Image-Slider-Game

The bug I'm having is on the first puzzle piece you move, if you click it again - when it moves back to the position it just came from - the puzzle piece changes to a different piece (in one instance I noticed that it was changing to the puzzle piece that is removed to initiate the game, but that might just be coincidence).

At first I thought the issue was with the setInterval method which is asynchronous (I was thinking that because I'm inside a loop maybe the reference loop iteration was getting messed up, but I'm now passing in the relevant iteration into the setInterval and the issue still occurs so it can't be that).

**UPDATE:**
I still think the problem is something to do with the setInterval. The main issue is when we start drawing the image onto the canvas the original x/y co-ordinates obviously have changed from what we expect them to be. I've noticed that the object which holds the co-ordinates for the puzzle piece we want to move is incorrect when we click on the same puzzle piece to move it back into the position it was just in. I noticed the drawnOnCanvasX/Y properties are different to what they should be, and that they now match the x/y co-ordinates of the empty_space variable? The fact that this doesn't happen all the time makes me think that the setInterval is not passing through the correct object from the loop into the function that executes on the interval?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I hadn't removed a particular item from the randomised Array.

For the game to work I needed to remove 1 puzzle piece, this allows the other pieces to have a space they can be moved into. Problem was that I had `clearRect` the piece I wanted but not actually removed it from the Array. So when I was looping through to find an item in the Array that had those exact X/Y co-ordinates it was finding the puzzle piece item that should have been removed (and because the piece that is removed is chosen randomly that's why sometimes that piece would be found via the loop first, and other times the correct piece would be found).

Christ that was painful.